# vba iterate through different folders dynamically

Tags: vba, loops, directory

I want to search in 25 different folders without hardcoding all of this. The folder path is the same for all.  The folder is "Mailbox It Support Center"/ different person's name here/"completed" I have the first two below so you can see what I'm doing.  I think I could use a for each *to search all of the mailbox names* but need to know how to iterate through those.

Sub CompletedEmailsDailyCount()

```
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount As Integer, EmailCount1 As Integer, EmailCount2 As Integer, EmailCount3    As     Integer, EmailCount4 As Integer
Dim EmailCount5 As Integer, EmailCount6 As Integer, EmailCount7 As Integer, EmailCount8 As     Integer, EmailCount9 As Integer
Dim EmailCount10 As Integer, EmailCount11 As Integer, EmailCount12 As Integer,     EmailCount13 As Integer, EmailCount14 As Integer
Dim EmailCount15 As Integer, EmailCount16 As Integer, EmailCount17 As Integer,     EmailCount18 As Integer, EmailCount19 As Integer
Dim EmailCount20 As Integer, EmailCount21 As Integer, EmailCount22 As Integer,     EmailCount23 As Integer, EmailCount24 As Integer
Dim EmailCount25 As Integer
Dim completed

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
On Error Resume Next

 Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("Onshore - Josh").Folders("completed")
     On Error GoTo 0
     ' check the folder so it exists
     If objFolder Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Such Folder": Exit Sub
     ' check through all mailitems in this folder for if the date matches yesterdays, if so, add one to emailcount
     For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
     If DateValue(Date - 1) = DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount15 = EmailCount15 + 1
     Next
     completed = completed + EmailCount15 'adds the completes from this mailbox to running total

Set objFolder1 = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("Onshore - Ashton").Folders("completed")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objFolder1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Such Folder": Exit Sub
    For Each MailItem In objFolder1.Items
    If DateValue(Date - 1) = DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount1 = EmailCount1 + 1
    Next
    completed = completed + EmailCount1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
Sub Tester()

'Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount() As Integer, arrNames
Dim completed, x As Long, num As Long

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    arrNames = Array("Josh", "Ashton") 'add other names here...
    ReDim EmailCount(LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames))

    For x = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center"). _
                Folders("Onshore - " & arrNames(x)).Folders("completed")
        On Error GoTo 0

        num = 0
        If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
            For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
               If DateValue(Date - 1) = _
                       DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then num = num + 1
            Next
        End If
        EmailCount(x) = num
        completed = completed + num

        Debug.Print arrNames(x), num

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Williams = RockStar. Works perfect, just need to add the names and it does all the work. Thank you so much.